# XCTestCase: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm just trying to make my 1st XCTestCase implementation, everything build fine, but when I'm executing the test case I face a "build failed":

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Node", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in Test01.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Its certainly a stupid configuration (compile/link) error, but I don't found the solution myself or on the existing posts :-(

Thanks in advance fro any help.

Have a good day.

Dexes

Here is a ZIPFile of my Xcode project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5f2buy3iukuwhde/Process.zip

and the complete errors is:

```
Build target Process

ProcessPCH /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch.pch Process/Process-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process/Process-Prefix.pch -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch.pch

CompileC /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o Process/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -include /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process/main.m -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

CompileC /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Router.o Process/Router.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -include /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Router.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Router.dia -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process/Router.m -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Router.o

CompileC /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Node.o Process/Node.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Process-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -include /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process-Prefix-dtfmmncegmgoctfiibxoezkmzpvp/Process-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Node.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Node.dia -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process/Node.m -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Node.o

Ld /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process normal x86_64
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process


Build target Process Tests

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process\ Tests.xctest/Contents/Info.plist Process\ Tests/Process\ Tests-Info.plist
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process\ Tests/Process\ Tests-Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -platform macosx -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process\ Tests.xctest/Contents/Info.plist

ProcessPCH /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch.pch Process\ Tests/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Process\ Tests.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process\ Tests/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch.pch

CompileC /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test01.o Test01.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Process\ Tests.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -include /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test01.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test01.dia -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Test01.m -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test01.o

CompileC /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process_Tests.o Process\ Tests/Process_Tests.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Process\ Tests.hmap -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -include /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Process\ Tests-Prefix-hezyicmbuhodqtcqannzgppzpcuv/Process\ Tests-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process_Tests.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process_Tests.dia -c /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process/Process\ Tests/Process_Tests.m -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process_Tests.o

Ld /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process\ Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/Process\ Tests normal x86_64
    cd /Users/dexes/Dropbox/XCode/Process
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process\ Tests.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework XCTest -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Intermediates/Process.build/Debug/Process\ Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Process\ Tests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dexes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Process-acrxpeunwuuvgebwfabvcnxpdwyl/Build/Products/Debug/Process\ Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/Process\ Tests

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Node", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Test01.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The error you supplied is extremely long, and in it's length is unhelpful - you could paste it into www.pastebin.com and provide a link to it if you must - but as it stands, it makes your question hard to follow.

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for your answer :-) Jay shows me the right direction to look at. have a good day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your Xcode test target (Project > Build Phases, little list on the right) -

**Does it include the source code (or framework) for your class?**

The error states that the linker doesn't add your compiled class to the binary so the test classes 'don't know' what to test..

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for you answer that give me the right direction to look at :-). By adding, the .m file in "Project > Build Phases > Compiles Sources" it's now working. Have a good day. Dexes